# Remove appended text clicking on it Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, append

I'm trying to find easiest and cleaner way to append and remove on appended span, div or text. Here is the code. What could be wrong?

```
/* HTML CODE */
<div id="appendHere" style="padding:10px;border:solid 1px red"></div>

/* Jquery CODE */
$('#appendHere').live('click' , function() {
    $('#appendHere').append('<span style="padding:10px;border:solid 1px green;">Simple text</span>');
});

$('#appendHere span').live('click' , function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: Which version of jquery you are using?.And you want to actually remove the span or show/hide would is enough?

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ru8emxbc/)

you can try to use [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Example :

```
$('#appendHere').on('click' , function(e) {
 $('#appendHere span').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

depending on which jQuery version you are using. Your use of `.live()` might be your first issue. try instead `.on()` example:

`$(document).on('click', '#appendHere span', function(){$(this).remove();});`

You could also just try something like

```
<style>
#addHere{padding:10px;border:solid 1px red;}
#addHere span{padding:10px;border:solid 1px green;}
</style>

<div id="appendHere" data-has_span="false"></div>
$(document).on('click', '#appendHere', function()
{
    $elem = $(this);
    if($elem.data('has_span') == "false")
    {
        $elem.prop('data-has_span', 'true').append('<span>Text here</span>');
    }
    else
    {
        $elem.prop('data-has_span', 'false').find('span').remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: I specify the use of #appendHere only because you may be facing a case of events bubbling. Meaning despite clicking on the span, you may still in fact or at least the browser is treating it as such. Be clicking on the parent div

Answer (score 1):

You'd better not use `live`, try instead `.bind()` or `.on()`

The question is when you click `span`, `div` is clicked and `time`

so you can try to do it like this:

```
$("appendHere").on("click", function(e) {
    if(!$(this).is($(e.target))) {
        return false;
    }
    $("<span>Text here</span>").appendTo($(this)).on("click", function() {
         $(this).remove();
    });
});
```